# Yii2 conflict with JQuery. TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

Tags: jquery, yii2

I am using Yii2 Framework. I have a conflict with jQuery. I used the jQuery dialog in specific view, but it didn't work:
Getting this error: `TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function`.

I disabled the default javascript of Yii2 in config/web.php by adding the below code:

```
'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                'js'=>[]
            ],
            'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                'js'=>[]
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

then I added the latest JQuery in specific view using the below code:

```
<?php   $this->registerJsFile('@web/js/jquery-3.2.1.js',['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD]);
    $this->registerJsFile('@web/js/jquery-ui.js',['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD]); ?>
```

then I registered my JS code in the same view:

```
<?php
        $this->registerJs(
            "$(document).ready(function($){
                 $('.add-product-button').on('click', function() {
                     var pid = $(this).attr('id');
                     var qty = $('#txt-qty-' + pid).val().trim();
                     $.ajax({
                         url: '?r=sales-order/addproduct',
                         data: {id: pid, value: qty},
                         beforeSend: function(){
                             $('#dialog').html('Adding product...');
                             $('#dialog').dialog();
                         },
                         success: function(data) {
                           $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                          }
                    });

                    return false;
                });

            }); ",
            View::POS_END,
            'my-button-handler'
        );
        ?>
    <?php }; ?>
```

The above makes jQuery dialog work. But the the yii2 javascript not working.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let Yii2 jquery assets as they were. The error you were getting was due to the use of the `dialog` function, which if I am not wrong is not part of jQuery but jQuery UI. Then, you need only to add jQuery UI to you page.

You can do that in different ways. On way would be installing the [Yii2 official JUI extension](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui) and adding it in the depends section of the asset bundle you are using. Or if you are going to use it very often, you can configure it as a dependence of Yii2's default jquery asset:

```
'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                'depends' => 'yii\jui\JuiAsset'
            ],
```

Comment: I followed the steps above. I think the first issue is solved but I got a new error. 

`Uncaught TypeError: elem.getClientRects is not a function`. I think it is related to compatibility between the jQuery and the jQuery UI. Any help?

Comment: I updated the JUI extensions and it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and this is how I solved it;

1. Navigate to `\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-jui\src\Dialog.php` at line 45 and add the following code;

   ```
   if($.fn.button && $.fn.button.noConflict !== undefined){

       var bootstrapButton = $.fn.button.noConflict();

       $.fn.bootstrapBtn = bootstrapButton;

   }
   ```